# Fill columns values according to a match between the columns names and the items of a list in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, series

I would like to fill columns values with a "yes" or "no" based on a match between the column name or its substrings and the items of a list in the same row but in another column. Is there a way to achieve this using pandas ?

```
Out[5]:
  Insurance:retailers Insurance:buyers Insurance:sales                Types
0                                                        [retailers, sales]
1                                                                   [sales]
2                                                       [retailers, buyers]
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result:

```
Out[7]:
  Insurance:retailers Insurance:buyers Insurance:sales                Types
0                 yes               no             yes   [retailers, sales]
1                  no               no             yes              [sales]
2                 yes              yes              no  [retailers, buyers]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about pandas, but from my understanding panda's DataFrames can be constructed from a python dictionary and vice versa.

So this should point you in the right direction

```
data={'Insurance:retailers':['No','No','No'],
  'Insurance:buyers':['No','No','No'],
  'Insurance:sales':['No','No','No'],
  'Types':[['retailers', 'sales'],['sales'],['retailers', 'buyers']]}

for idx, entry in enumerate(data['Types']):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if any(element in key for element in entry):
            data[key][idx]='yes'
            
print(data)
```